# Could someone explain a little about this statement about mysqli close function?

Tags: php, mysqli

Listed here on the mysqli documentation site, one of the comments says

> You should always use mysqli_kill()
>   function before mysqli_close() to
>   actually close and free up the tcp
>   socket being used by PHP.  Garbage
>   collection after script execution nor
>   mysqli_close() do not kill the tcp
>   socket on their own.  The socket would
>   otherwise remain in 'wait' state for
>   approximately 30 seconds, and any
>   additional page loads/connection
>   attempts would only add to the total
>   number of open tcp connections.  This
>   wait time does not appear to be
>   configurable via PHP settings.
>
> Also as of this version, mysqli
>   created links cannot be "deactivated",
>   and will continue to accumulate in
>   process memory until the PHP server or
>   process is restarted, essentially
>   making mysqli.max_links = -1 required.

Could someone explain what this means, and if mysqli.max_links should be set, how so, and if i should be using mysqli_kill();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't found that rational, mysql can be connected via socket on localhost

> Be careful using **mysqli::kill** before mysqli::close.
>
> Killing the thread before actually closing the connection will leave the connection open! And depending on your max_connections and max_user_connections (by default the same), this could result in a "Max connections reached for **** user" message.

from : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.kill.php

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate the help, so some advice, should i use close, then kill after?

Comment: just close ... you can do some testing using localhost wamp, and monitor the number of connection using `show full processlist;`