# Are there any downsides to having mysqli_close in the footer of every page?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, mysqli, database-connection

I was taught to put mysqli_close in the footer.php that I include in every page as "best practice". ;)

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822291/when-should-i-use-mysqli-kill-and-mysqli-close) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351633/why-use-mysqli-close) it is not exactly necessary, but would you go as far as saying it's bad practice?

Should I put the effort into removing it and only using it when necessary?

I can't imagine my server taking anything but a negligible performance hit from this extra line of script. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not best practice, it's not a very bad practice, it's not good practice.

As explained in the two Q/A you mentioned, mysqli_close has to be used when its needed : When you've done what you needed to do with your database **AND** when you still have many things to do in your script.

Short answer : Always using it at the very end of your scripts is 99.99% useless.

Comment: I will remove it then. K.I.S. +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

If you don't release a resource that is in use in your script, it will be released when your script has completed. So, you aren't saving much more than a few bytes of disk space by removing it. The process of releasing the resource will happen with or without the mysqli_close.

Comment: So it's completely unnececary if used in this way?

Comment: If used at the end of a script, it is not necessary. It is implied.